# navigator.app.exitApp(); is not working in cordova app (Android, Vue, Quasar Framework)

Tags: javascript, android, vuejs2, quasar-framework

i tried exiting app on my android app.
but, it's not working.

I am using quasarframework, vue2 and javascript.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xneSO.jpg)

'yes' touch is not working.

help me. thank you.

```
mounted: function() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
methods: {
  onDeviceReady () {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", this.onBackKey, false);
  },
  onBackKey() {
    Dialog.create({
      title: 'Exit',
      message: 'exit?',
      buttons: [
        {
          label: 'No',
          handler () {
          }
        },
        {
          label: 'Yes',
          handler: () => {
            this.onBackKeyResult();
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  },
  onBackKeyResult (buttonIndex) {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
      navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
  };
}
```

- Evironment

> quasar version  : Quasar CLI v0.6.5, App running on Quasar v0.14.9
>
> cordova -version : 8.0.0
>
> cordova-android : 7.0.0
>
> cordova plugin : "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview": "^2.4.0", "cordova-plugin-fcm": "2.1.2", "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0", "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3"